# Adding some commands from e.g. WordPress to Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, wordpress

I code a lot with NP++ for WordPress. My question is, is it possible (or an extension available) to have several commands (do_shortcode(); if_has_thumbnail; etc...) pre-defined? Like suggestions ?

Any ideas? Thanks,
Brainbug

Comment: So far I've just found "QuickText" for NP++ ... looks good actually, but any other hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FingerText](https://github.com/erinata/FingerText) is a good snippet manager for NPP. Here is a [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zo8mGJjSEBo) on its usage.

A more general alternative would be [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com). You can define your own snippets and automate much more.